# Where did 3.5 come from?

Tags: quadratics

This is a homework question.

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGb2W.png). I know the solution, but I don't know where it came from. The videos say nothing. The equation is $d(v) = (2.15v^2)/(64.4f)$ I need to solve for $f$, so I tried plugging in the numbers from the table into the equation and solving. I got approximately $0.018$ by solving, yet apparently the answer is $3.5$. How do I solve problems like this, and what was my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try plugging in, for example, the values $v = 20$ and $d = 38$ from the table. This gives us
$$
d = \frac{2.15 v^2}{64.4 f} \implies 38 = \frac{2.15 \cdot 20^2}{64.4 f}.
$$
We now solve for $f$. Multiply both sides by the denominator, then divide both sides by the coefficient to solve for $f$.
$$
38 = \frac{2.15 \cdot 20^2}{64.4 f} \implies (38 \cdot 64.4) f = 2.15 \cdot 20^2 \implies f = \frac{2.15 \cdot 20^2}{38 \cdot 64.4} \approx 0.35.
$$
If we forget the exponent attached to $v$, then we instead end up with
$$
f = \frac{2.15 \cdot 20}{38 \cdot 64.4} \approx 0.018.
$$
I suspect that this is the source of your error.

Comment: Also don't forget that the hundredths place means two decimal places, so even if $0.018$ was the correct number, you would have needed to input $0.02$.